# Lodash orderBy Array Object

Tags: lodash

I manually created a set of unordered entries  [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJHrH.jpg)
and I was wondering how I could properly apply the orderBy to iterate through the "order" entry.

I did use the code below but it still returns the same unordered entries I first created.

`_.orderBy(rows, 'order', 'asc')`

What am I doing wrong here? :(

Comment: Are you using the list returned from the `orderBy` call? lodash doesn't sort the list in-place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey there I think you only got a small error inside your idea, this one should be working:

```
const _ = require('lodash')

const UserOrders = [
  [{ order: '2' }, { order: '1' }, { order: '3' }],
  [{ order: '3' }, { order: '1' }, { order: '2' }],
]

const sortedUserOrders = UserOrders.map(orders =>
    _.orderBy(orders, ['order'], ['asc'])
)
```

this is the output of my code:

```
​​​​​[ [ { order: '1' }, { order: '2' }, { order: '3' } ],​​​​​
​​​​​  [ { order: '1' }, { order: '2' }, { order: '3' } ] ]
```

I also recommend you to take a look into the [lodash documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#orderBy)

Comment: Thank you so much! This did the trick, I knew I had to use .map somewhere when I kept stumbling upon it on my searches.

Comment: @RoboKy feel free to upvote it aswell, if liked the answer!